# Run MySQL Query in R in which values to be search are in a DF

Tags: mysql, r

I have a DF with several columns, but there is one column that is a result of some preprocessing stages, this column contains the values that I need to search with a MySQL query.

How can I make the query read the column or another DF with this info directly instead of adding them manually?

DF example:

```
id
3061945
7392492
7491277
7855936
8125589
7060737
5614627
7597607
```

Query:

```sql
select c.Id as sfdcContactID,
    c.FirstName, 
    c.ID__c as uid 
from Contact as c 
where c.ID__c in ('values to be looked based on the DF’);
```

Comment: How to run a query in R that uses the values of a DF as the search values of the query?

Comment: Why do you not comply by editing your question? See `sprintf`.

Answer (score 1):

Since there could be potentially thousands even millions of values in dataframe, consider exporting dataframe to a MySQL temp table then join it in your query. Below are several ways using database APIs or command line ultimately to create a dataframe of query results.

**RODBC**

```
# REPLACES TEMP WITH EVERY CALL
sqlSave(conn, "temptablename", df, append = FALSE)   

# RUNS QUERY AND IMPORTS RESULTS INTO DATAFRAME
newdf <- sqlQuery(conn, paste0("SELECT c.Id as sfdcContactID, c.FirstName, c.ID__c as uid",
                               " FROM Contact c",
                               " INNER JOIN temptablename t ON c.ID__c = t.id"))
```

**RMySQL**

```
# REPLACES TEMP WITH EVERY CALL
dbWriteTable(conn, "temptablename", df, overwrite = TRUE)

# RUNS QUERY AND IMPORTS RESULTS INTO DATAFRAME
newdf <- dbGetQuery(conn, paste0("SELECT c.Id as sfdcContactID, c.FirstName, c.ID__c as uid",
                                 " FROM Contact c",
                                 " INNER JOIN temptablename t ON c.ID__c = t.id"))
```

**Command Line**

R - CSV Export

```
write.csv("path/to/file.csv", df)
```

SQL *(save as .sql file)*

```sql
# IMPORT CSV FILE TO TABLE
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
INTO TABLE temptablename
FIELDS TERMINATED BY
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';

# EXPORT QUERY TO CSV FILE
SELECT c.Id as sfdcContactID, c.FirstName, c.ID__c as uid
FROM Contact c
INNER JOIN temptablename t ON c.ID__c = t.id
INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/output.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

R - CMD/Shell call to mysql client

```
system("mysql -u username -p password db_name < /path/to/file.sql")

df <- read.csv("/path/to/output.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using ODBC, so you won't be able to get MySQL to read data from a data frame on the client.

You could:

1. Construct a prepared statement in the database and pass the ID values as parameters of the query.
2. Or you could construct a string in R (using the `paste()` function) to hold your SQL query, and create a list of ID values as part of the query string.
3. Or you could upload the ID values to a table in MySQL and use that in your SQL query.

The first method is probably the most secure, but if you have a large number of ID values it may be slow.

Method 2 is easy and flexible but is potentially a security risk - it could open you up to SQL injection (but if you can't create objects in the database then the second method may be your only option).

The last method is ideal if you need to use indexes, but it might be overkill if you only want a few rows.